# How to: Dynamic var's name change on AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

It is possible to dynamic change the name of the vars is AS3 using flash? I mean, create for example 10 vars with one root name like: myvar and then incrementing a number, like myvar0, myvar1, myvar2 and so on.

I while ago i achived this in AS2 with this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var mc = _root.attachMovie("my_square", "my_square_"+i, i);
    mc._x = i * 50;
}
```

But now im in AS3 and the var a need to copy is this:

```
var caja1:HTMLTextBlock = new HTMLTextBlock();
```

How can in generates in a FOR, caja1, caja2, caja3 and sp.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a very simple and clean way of achieving this is creating an array.

```
var caja:Array = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    caja[i] = new HTMLTextBlock();
}
```

Just remember that the first entry in the array starts with 0 and not 1 (i.e. caja[0]).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5):

Hey Domingo,
I've been out of AS2 for a while now so I'm not going to be absolutely sure if this is what you're looking for but I think it is.

```
var myObjects:Object = {};

for(var i:Number = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    myObjects["caja"+i]=new HTMLTextBlock();
    addChild(myObjects["caja"+i]); //if using Flex 4 containers use addElement(myObjects["caja"+i]);
    myObjects["caja"+i].x=i*50; //assuming here container has an absolute layout
}
```

What you'd be doing here is creating a new object which has dynamic properties to resolve a property in AS3 you can either use (dot operator) myObject.something or (associative array?) myObject["something"] and it will work the same.

Comment: @DomingoSL. The posted code looks like valid AS3. Did you give it a try?

Comment: yah this is valid AS3 give it a shot